# Symfony Routing: Why does Symfony redirects my POST request?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, http

I experience a strange behaviour with my Symfony app. I use a controller as a webhook for facebook, where I expect a post request.

My access.log of the webserver shows me the following:

```
[/Mar/2017:11:48:50 +0100] "POST /app_dev.php/bot HTTP/1.1" 301 3810 "-" "-"
[/Mar/2017:11:48:50 +0100] "GET /app_dev.php/bot/ HTTP/1.1" 200 476 "-" "-"
```

So I assume that my app does redirect the POST request to a GET request somehow. I have no idea where I should start looking for that?

My rounting looks like this:

```
backend:
    resource: "@BackendBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /backend

bot:
    resource: "@BotBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /bot

# redirecting the root
root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /backend
        permanent: true
```

And my controller in the BotBundle:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
  $logger = $this->get('logger');
  $logger->info('REQUEST METHOD: '.$request->getMethod());
```

Only logs GET requests, POST requests never show up, I only see the 301 in the access.log.

Maybe it has to do something with the apache?

Does anybody have a tip how I can debug this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show the rest of BotBundle/Controller.php

Comment: Try POSTing directly to `/bot/` (with the trailing slash included) instead of just `/bot`.

Comment: @ccKep yes, that was the solution to the problem, thanks a lot!! Can you explain what is happening there? If you would post it as an answer i can accept it.

Comment: I am not exactly sure if the internals regarding Symfonys routing, I just noticed your HTTP 301 redirect from `/bot` to `/bot/`. I suspect it has to do with your controller annotation being `/` and prefixed with `/bot` in your routing.yml so it becomes `/bot/`. You could take a look at `php app/console router:debug` to print the exact routing table if I remember correctly.

Comment: You are using permenant redirect in routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony, a route with or without the trailing slash is the same route. But, for the sake of having the right route, you will get the one with a trailing slash.

Since you are posting to `/app_dev.php/bot`, you will get redirected to `/app_dev.php/bot/` with trailing slash. The issue here is that HTTP specifications says that when a POST gets a redirect, the browser should follow the redirect changing the verb to GET, to avoid issues about idempotence.